# Add leading zeros using javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, padding

How would i use javascript or jquery to add a leading zero to this?

```
for (im=1;im<=31;im++){
     days[im]=everyDay[im];
}
```

Comment: Do you want `days[im]` to always be a string of length 2?  What is `everyDay`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel yea it would only be for the days of the month

Comment: everyDay[im].shufflin'

Comment: @Craig everyDay array consist what? Is it consists both string and integers

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
for (var t, im=1; im<=31; im++){ 
  t = everyDay[im]; 
  days[im] = (t < 10? 0 : '') + t; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want leading zeros in your `days` array. You can create another array with days as strings like this, and use one or the other where it belongs or use `parseInt()` on the new array:

```
var days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
    strDays = [];

for (var i = 0, l = days.length; i < l; i++) {
    strDays.push(String(days[i]).length < 2 ? '0' + days[i] : String(days[i]));
}

// `strDays` prints: ["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]
```

**EDIT:**
 Even shorter:

```
var strDays = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
    strDays.push(('' + i).length < 2 ? '0' + i : '' + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend it with a 0, and then take the last two characters:

```
var days = {};
for (im=1;im<=31;im++){
     days[im] = ('0' + im).substr(-2);
}
```

Comment: This gives me the zeros up to 09 but also 10 becomes 01. I'm guessing becuase it adds a zero then subtracts the 3 number 20 becomes 020 then 02

Comment: @PaulP—better read how [String.prototype.substring](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.15) works. It's not how you seem to expect. In particular, step 6: `Let finalStart be min(max(intStart, 0), len).`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (im=1;im<=31;im++){
  days[im] = (everyDay[im] < 10 ? '0' : '') + everyDay[im];
}
```

Comment: @RobG, Yes, I read the OP: "How would i use javascript **or** jquery..."

Comment: I just want to see how you work jQuery into the answer. Hey, you got more rep for the reply comment than the answer! ;-)

Comment: @RobG, strange.  Here, have a fix of jQuery: `$.each(everyDay, function (day, im) { if (1 <= im && im <= 31) { days[i] = (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day; } })`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var im=1;im<=31;im++){
     var x = parseInt(everyDay[im]);
     if(x < 10)
     days[im]='0' + x;
     else days[im]= x;
}
```

Comment: Now `days` contains some strings and some numbers : `[, "01", "02", "03", ..., "08", "09", 10, 11, ..., 31]`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I have updated my answer, Is it fine now? If not tell me the fault, I'l try to correct that one

Comment: @pravalika—there is no need for `parseInt`, an early step in the evaluation of the expression will be to convert `x` to a number primitive.